# Showing error while running nodemon server.js

Tags: reactjs, nodemon

I have installed nodemon using these commands

```
npm install nodemon
```

npm installed successfully,

after running `nodemon server.js` showing error

```
'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps could you try installing and saving the react-scripts dependency and seeing if this resolves your issue:

```
npm i -S react-scripts
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: do you have any other solution?

Comment: sure perhaps your node_modules directory has been corrupted. Could you try removing it and reinstalling? This assumes all your dependencies are listed within your package.json file. Additionally, remove your package-lock.json file

Comment: @PrabhudevVatnal did those steps help resolve your issue?